# how to use LIKE clause in mysql when using with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm trying to use like in mysql from php and i write this code

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM items order by create_at desc where content LIKE '" . $content . "%'")
  or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

but it says there is an error in my syntax it says like this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'where content LIKE 'c%'' at line 1

Comment: problem in ordering, SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION ORDER LIMIT. you should follow mysql order of statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Order BY` clause always come in the end, use `WHERE` clause first and then use `ORDER BY`

Solution would be this :

```
SELECT * FROM items where content LIKE 'yourVariable%' ORDER BY create_at DESC
```

Comment: Logically speaking , we get data first and then sort it later!

Comment: ...except `LIMIT`

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code should be:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM items  where content LIKE '" . $content . "%' order by create_at desc";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Query clauses sequence should be :

- Select
- From
- join
- where
- group by
- order by
- limit

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM items order by create_at desc where content LIKE '%.$content.%'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```